# Is it possible to implement custom validation on a IRuleValue in a custom benefit?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have a custom benefit that contains a single property for the BizFX user to enter:

```
public class GetFreeItemAction : ICartLineAction
{
    public IRuleValue<string> SellableItemId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to validate the value of `SellableItemId`? I would like the user to enter the ID on the format `Entity-SellableItem-1234`.

If this is not possible, I wonder if it is possible to reuse the "special" `Item Id` field that is used in some qualifications, on a custom benefit? An example: The *Is Item Pre-orderable* qualification contains an `Item Id` field that validates if the item actually exists in the selected catalog:

[image]

I am on Sitecore XC 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar in our OSS promotion extensions: [Nyxie](https://github.com/avivasolutionsnl/Nyxie/blob/master/src/Nyxie.Plugin.Promotions/Actions/CartFreeGiftAction.cs).

It should be enough to just rename the `SellableItemId` property to `TargetItemId`. The default promotion plugin contains a `GetPromotionBenefitDetailsViewBlock` that will automatically add the Catalog and Item Ids input fields to the Benefit, when it encounters a field named `TargetItemId`.

Comment: I will try it out - so this is the only way to perform custom validation on rules?